# How can an Oracle scheduled chain include a step which calls a program with arguments

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

When defining an Oracle scheduled chain I need to call a scheduled program and I need to be able to pass parameters.
The parameters can be declared statically (hard-coded) in the chain definition, but how do I actually call a program and pass arguments?

I have looked at various docs on the web, but there does not appear to be a way to pass the arguments, is this correct?

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/scheduse009.htm

Comment: Where do the values come from that you need to pass in? Are they always the same, or do you need to set them dynamically in some way?

Comment: They can remain constant as defined in the chain. No dynamic cleverness is required, however I need to override the default values as defined on the program.

Answer (score 2):

I'm struggling to remember how I tackled this problem a few years ago.

I believe that I might have used different programs to call the same stored procedure depending on what parameter values I wanted to pass in, which was every bit as inconvenient as it sounds. That requires a lot of control and thought over the names for the programs, and for some cases it was so clearly inadequate that I started using programs with a program_type of PLSQL_BLOCK so I could just call the required stored procedure with parameter values hard-coded into an anonymous block.

Still inconvenient, and in retrospect what might work well is to use PLSQL_BLOCK-type programs that read a table of parameter values from which the required ones could be selected in the anon block to be passed into a stored procedure. You could build the arguments and their values from that.

Also not convenient, but it would have the advantage of allowing inter-chain step messaging of a sort, by allowing a chain step to set parameters for subsequent steps.

It also allows parameters to be varied without having to redefine schedule objects, which I always found to be so [fraught with peril](http://oraclesponge.wordpress.com/2011/01/20/another-dbms_scheduler-chain-rule-issue/) that I'd always entirely drop a chain and recreate it rather than tweak a single part of it.

There may be a clever way of doing all of this using the advanced queueing methodology, but I have not dabbled in that.

Comment: Thanks @David, I'm also currently defining multiple programs which execute the same job with distinct default parameter values. Of course the answer that I was hoping for was ... here is the missing link for the syntax that you need, but thanks for letting me know that I'm not the only one to struggle with this issue.